# Implement Google-like AutoComplete on Searches

Tags: feature-request, search

I would like the search box to have AutoComplete and provide you a list of popular searches based on what you type, similar to what Google has:

> [image: Auto complete sample]

Can this feature please be added?

Comment: I'd rather have Google like search results...

Comment: I'd prefer search results that were relevant first, but following the same heuristics for words together may improve the searching experience

Comment: Well, it already has "did you mean" feature, so guess that can be the next step.